# Controllable color blending?

Tags: directx, blending, alpha-blending

I'm relatively new to color blending in DirectX, and I'm hoping there is a relatively simple answer to this question. I am targeting Direct10.1.
What I am trying to achieve is colour blending of two overlapping 2D shapes, where the blend factor between the two layers varies (in quite a simple manner).

The shapes in the output I want should be completely opaque. I can achieve the blend variation I need very easily using alpha blending and modifying the alpha value in the pixel shader, but of course this then ends up giving me a final image with areas of partial transparency. One way I think I could resolve this would be to simply render the original render target again in a quad, and multiply out the alpha values to give me a 100% opaque images, but I have a niggling feeling that the blend operation I want must be possible via some blend state configuration.